# continue button missing for free event registration

Tags: wordpress, civievent

If I configure a free event the online registration page has a "continue" button after the registration fields.

However if I have a paid event with a free (ie $0.00) price, when the $0.00 price is selected the payment (paypal) block disappears but no "continue" button displays?

civi 4.7.10
wordpress 4.6

Comment: Could you try replicating this bug on http://demo.civicrm.org and see if it happens in the latest version of CiviCRM?  This might just need an upgrade.  Also, take a read of https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19484 and see if you're having the same problem?  It sounds similar, but a) slightly different, b) that person only sees the problem on CiviCRM 4.6.  However, they DO have a patch!

Comment: This appears to happen if the payment processor is set to PayPal Express - this is triggered by https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php#L645-L656

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an issue with how PayPal express - payment processor works in civicrm, if you have multiple options on the event and the customer chooses to pay nothing and only opts for free part of the event. the continue button disappears as well paypal express button goes away, I've been using paypal standard instead to get around the issue.

Comment: Indeed, we use Paypal Standard, as we have some events where people are paying $0 and others are paying more (they didn't want to do discount codes).

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this because the problem remains at least up to 5.48.2.

I have worked around the problem by adding the following code as an HTML block in the profile used on that page. It runs a function every three seconds that checks to see if the page value is $ 0.00 and if it is unsets the "display: none" value that has been given to the continue button.

```
<script>
      function myFunction () {
        var node = document.getElementById('pricevalue');
        var nodetext = node.innerText;
        if (nodetext == "$ 0.00") {
            document.getElementById("_qf_Register_upload-bottom").style.display = ""
        }
      }
      setInterval(myFunction, 3000);
</script>
```