# Zero fee for a paid event

Tags: civievent

I host a donation-based event, and allow people to register online using a PayPal Payment Processor.

I want to have different options for donations, but also none at all (zero amount).

I tried to use Regular Fees with one of them set to zero, I tried Price Sets, I tried CiviDiscount. But all have the same problem - once the amount to pay is zero, the 'Pay' button of PayPal disappears, and instead there is no button to register free from charge.

I also tried to name the 'Pay Later' label as '€0', but then the user still has to choose one of the normal fees, and then choose the '€0' payment processor rather than the PayPal one, which is very confusing.

How can I do that choosing the zero fee will simply allow to continue and register without paying anything?

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16149/continue-button-missing-for-free-event-registration/25724#25724 This is still an issue, im sure subject matter experts at Civi would know how to solve the issue: more information in post continue button missing for free event registration

Comment: I've provided a workaround at that Q as well as the problem persists. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16149/continue-button-missing-for-free-event-registration

Answer (score 2):

If you make a price set, create a price field and make the field not required, you should be good to go. The person simply wont choose a price option and registration will continue as normal. You should also be able to add a no cost (value 0) fee and registration will also continue as normal.

Can you explain more about your setup?  CMS, CiviCRM version, what you mean by 'Pay' button of PayPal disappears.

Comment: I'm finding that even when a price set is optional, the registration process insists that a value be chosen from the price set. So I've gone back to having a zero cost option for the paid event, and having a lot of $0.00 contributions collected in the system. Running 5.32.1 under Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a version of civi pre 4.7.x then were some related bugs eg https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16929. Knowing what version of civi you are on helps folk answer you more helpfully but that ticket does clearly suggest that a $0 in the Price Set options should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit this issue myself and after a bit of testing I think I've worked out that there is an issue with the "Paypal-express" payment processor.

Image below has paypal-express set as processor

[image: Test event with paypal-express selected as payment option]

With payment methods set to test or "paypal standard" the continue button is there, but if the "paypal-express" payment processor is selected the contine button disappears for zero dollar payments.

Image below with paypal-standard set.

[image: test event with paypal standard set as payment option]