# How to have form not require billing address if zero fee in priceset is selected in Event?

Tags: civievent, forms, price-sets

Using CiviEvent, I have an event with a priceset that includes various prices, but also a zero fee option.  The billing block information should not be required if zero fee is selected, but I can't get it to work.

I am open to ideas for workarounds.  I am not able to upgrade the CiviCRM version at this point.

On the web event registration form, before clicking continue:

- If a non-zero fee is selected, the billing block correctly appears
  and shows as required to fill in if Paypal not selected.
- If the zero fee is selected, the billing block correctly does not appear.

BUT

When the user clicks the continue button after selecting the zero-fee option, an Error message comes up about fields in the billing bock being required.  This is despite the billing block  not being shown to the user (correctly as there should not be shown when zero fee).

For the first-time click, it also includes billing firstname/lastname, which I would expect to be taken from the Individual firstname/lastname that were filled in

If I click the continue a second time, it no longer mentions billing firstname/lastname, but it still shows some billing block fields as being required.

Billing First Name is a required field.
Billing Last Name is a required field.
Street Address is a required field.
City is a required field.
State/Province is a required field.
Postal Code is a required field.
Country is a required field.

The second time:

Street Address is a required field.
City is a required field.
State/Province is a required field.
Postal Code is a required field.
Country is a required field.

I have version 4.6 so it might the bug below, but I am not sure.
[Zero fee for a paid event](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24741/zero-fee-for-a-paid-event)

thanks,
Michele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was definitely the known bug.
I upgraded to  4.6.38 and no longer have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16929.
You might need to apply the 3 patch that were submitted to this issue -

- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7191
- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7286
- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7289

The first two are pretty longer patch so not sure if they will be applied directly. Recommendation is to upgrade CiviCRM to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to write [`hook_civicrm_buildForm`](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) and use form id as a trigger in if condition and use jQuery to remove/disable billing section when specific option is selected.